# Scroll WKInterfaceController back to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm currently displaying a long label of text plus a button below it to go to the 'next' message.

When the next button is pressed the label adjusts it's height automagically thanks to watch kit's strange auto sizing mechanisms; however the screen does not change positions. I want to scroll the InterfaceController back to the top whenever the label updates. Is this possible with the current Watch Kit SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Apple employee said

> Scrolling to the top is only supported on WKInterfaceTable. If you'd
>   like this functionality on a WKInterfaceController, please file a
>   request for it at https://bugreport.apple.com. Thanks! :)

on the developer forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/1074525#1074525

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in watchOS 4. Just use the `scrollToObject:atScrollPosition:animated:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no API for the interface controller to scroll to top. But I did a workaround for the same.

1. Add a WKInterfaceTable to the top.
2. Set the Height of the Row Controllers Group to 2 and set the
   background color to black.
3. Set the number of rows to 1.
4. Call the below method.

`func scrollInterfaceToTop() {
        tableView.setHidden(false)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: 0)
        tableView.setHidden(true)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 ... this works for me:

where this call is

1. inside the WKInterfaceController class of the WatchKit Extension app,
2. my 'btnPrevTee' is a button located at the top of the watch face

   scroll(to:btnPrevTee, at:.top, animated:true)

ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2874208-scroll